# Eclipse - Collections show error in debug variable view

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, eclipse-2019-06

Using Eclipse 2019-06 and OpenJDK 11 for a personal project. At the moment when I debug, tells me that entrySet() is undefined for the Map___ type like so:

[image: Debug variable view]

for reference, the settings I have at the moment which seem most relevant:

[image: Logical Structures settings view]

[image: Detail Formatters settings view]

Is there something I'm not aware of here? Any settings I need to change? This issue seems to affect every type that extends `Collection`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asked around and did more research, this issue [is an Eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=543604). This issue should be fixed with [Eclipse 4.12](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/eclipse/releases/4.12.0) or higher, which releases on June 19th, 2019.